# Does Firebug Lite have Javascript Profiling?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

Im testing javascript profiles and I wanted to try something different from Chrome Developer tools.

Does Firebug Lite for Google Chrome have Javascript Profiling enabled?

Comment: No. http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#WhatsNot

Comment: You're welcome.  Sorry about the short comment, work's been tough today :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Rocket Hazmat:

> No. [getfirebug.com/firebuglite#WhatsNot](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#WhatsNot)